# Dynamic conditions without dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables

```
KeyWord Table
    | KeyWord1   |    Operator |     KeyWord2 |
    | -----------|------------:|:------------:|
    | Tom        |       AND   |     Harry    |
    | Krishna    |       OR    |     Radha    |
    | Raju       |       AND   |     Radha    |

Text Table

    | Id         |       Text                     |
    | -----------|-------------------------------:|
    | 1          |       Tom and Harry Nice       |
    | 2          |       Tom Harry Raju Radha Nice|
    | 3          |       Raju Radha Tom Nice      |
```

Expected result is

Result

```
    | Id         |       Text                     |
    | -----------|-------------------------------:|
    | 2          |       Tom Harry Raju Radha Nice|
```

The result is because of `(Tom AND Harry) AND (Krishna OR Radha) AND (Raju AND Radha)`. I need to use `LIKE` operator (`LIKE '%'+tbl.Text+'%'`) to get the boolean expression.

If there is no non dynamic sql approach, let me know the best dynamic sql approach.

Comment: The whole benefit of dynamic SQL is having dynamic conditions like that. Why don't you want to use dynamic SQL?

Comment: @mattytommo easy to read and maintain. Also the query will be much longer if conditions table is large. a chance of slow query?

Comment: So you think storing operands and search keywords in a table is easy to maintain? I think that went out the window when that table was conceived.

Comment: @mattytommo Then, how to save filter conditions in a table?

Answer (score 1):

The following works without Dynamic SQL or cursors/while-loops. A few notes about it:

- Since "text" is a reserved word, I renamed:

  - the [Text] table to be [TheText]
  - the [Text] field to be [TheText]
- It uses a correlated-NOT EXISTS to throw out invalid records. This works due to:

  - all of the "Keyword" sets are "AND"ed together, hence they must all be true

    - they must all be true, hence any one of them that is false invalidates the record
    - a single false condition gives us the same answer as all correct conditions, if we only put a `NOT` in front of the `EXISTS`
    - it is *much* easier to look for a single mismatch than to make sure all test cases match
    - since we are looking for the inverse/opposite of the conditions (as noted in the Keywords table), we reverse the AND/OR logic via:

      - True AND True => NOT True OR NOT True
      - True OR True => NOT True AND NOT True
- The `OR` condition set in the test data is not a good test as it has a value that is required by one of the `AND` condition sets (i.e. `Radha`), hence the `OR` set isn't needed and won't help determine if the logic works for both `AND` and `OR` conditions. So:

  - I changed the name `Radha` to `Bob`
  - I added a 4th row in [TheText] that has `Krishna` and which is the only row that should (and does!) match

Code:

```sql
DECLARE @TheText TABLE (ID INT, TheText NVARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO @TheText VALUES (1, N'Tom and Harry Nice');
INSERT INTO @TheText VALUES (2, N'Tom Harry Raju Radha Nice');
INSERT INTO @TheText VALUES (3, N'Raju Radha Tom Nice');
INSERT INTO @TheText VALUES (4, N'Tom Harry Raju Radha Krishna Nice');

DECLARE @Keywords TABLE (
  Keyword1 NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  Operator NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  Keyword2 NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @Keywords VALUES ('Tom', 'AND', 'Harry');
INSERT INTO @Keywords VALUES ('Krishna', 'OR', 'Bob');
INSERT INTO @Keywords VALUES ('Raju', 'AND', 'Radha');

SELECT *
FROM   @TheText txt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT *
           FROM   @Keywords kw
           WHERE  (
                      kw.Operator = N'AND'
                AND   (
                         txt.TheText NOT LIKE N'%' + kw.Keyword1 + N'%'
                  OR     txt.TheText NOT LIKE N'%' + kw.Keyword2 + N'%'
                      )
                  )
           OR     (
                      kw.Operator = N'OR'
                AND   (
                         txt.TheText NOT LIKE N'%' + kw.Keyword1 + N'%'
                  AND    txt.TheText NOT LIKE N'%' + kw.Keyword2 + N'%'
                      )
                  )
          );
```

Result:

```
ID  TheText
4   Tom Harry Raju Radha Krishna Nice
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, there is any other way to do without dynamic SQL.
Try below code this will surely help you. I tried in sybase it worked awesome!

```html
--Create Sample Tables
--Keyword Table
create table #tempKeyword
(col_id numeric(5,0) identity , Keyword1 varchar(100),Operator varchar(100),Keyword2 varchar(100))

insert into #tempKeyword (Keyword1,Operator,Keyword2)
select * 
from
(
select 'Tom' as Keyword1,  'AND' as Operator, 'Harry' as Keyword2
union all
select 'Krishna' as Keyword1,  'OR' as Operator, 'Radha' as Keyword2
union all
select 'Raju' as Keyword1,  'AND' as Operator, 'Radha' as Keyword2
) a

print 'Keyword Table'
select * from #tempKeyword


--Text table
select * into #tempText from
(
select 1 as Id, 'Tom and Harry Nice' as Text
union all
select 2 as Id, 'Tom Harry Raju Radha Nice' as Text
union all
select 3 as Id, 'Raju Radha Tom Nice' as Text
) b

print 'Text Table'
select * from #tempText

SET NOCOUNT ON

---- Script begin
declare @Keyword1  varchar(100)
declare @Operator  varchar(100)
declare @Keyword2  varchar(100)
declare @sql varchar(1000)

--settin loop counter variables
declare @start int
declare @end int
select @start=min(col_id),@end=max(col_id) from #tempKeyword 

--loop for #temp table
WHILE (@start <= @end)            
BEGIN

    select top 1 @Keyword1=Keyword1,@Operator=Operator,@Keyword2=Keyword2
    from #tempKeyword where col_id=@start

    --eliminate each rows with NOT condition from result table.
    select @sql='delete from #tempText where not ( Text like ''%' + @Keyword1 + 
    '%''' + @Operator +' Text like ''%' + @Keyword2 + '%'')'
    execute(@sql)
    
    --set Counter for Loop
    set @start = @start + 1
end

SET rowcount 0
--Result Output
print 'Results'
select * from #tempText
```

I hope this helps :)